# Why does PHP filter_var say that this is a valid email address?

Tags: php, email, email-validation, filter-var

I use the `filter_var` PHP function to validate email address when a user signs up to my site.

I use this code from the post:

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

then later I do:

```
if(!$email) {
  // return to the form 
}
else {
  // send registration info
}
```

now when I `var_dump($email)`, I get the output:

```
string(23) "user."name"@example.com"
```

I would like to know why this does not return false. I think the double quotes are not acceptable, so why does PHP say it’s valid?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It *is* a [valid email address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part) :

> A quoted string may exist as a dot separated entity within the
>   local-part or it may exist when the outermost quotes are the outermost
>   chars of the local-part (e.g. abc."defghi".xyz@example.com or
>   "abcdefghixyz"@example.com are allowed. abc"defghi"xyz@example.com is
>   not; neither is abc\"def\"ghi@example.com).

Comment: thanks for the info, i think it's ridiculous they allow such chars

Comment: @fred Not everyone speaks and writes English. Double quotes are often used for characters from other languages. Not so ridiculous now, eh?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem (see Dalmas on why it's valid) and here's how I fixed it:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

eg:

```
$email = 'user."name"@example.com';
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

will output:

```
string(21) "user.name@example.com"
```

Then you can validate the email using your validation.

you can get more information on the [php site](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php)

Comment: thanks for this answer, i was wondering how can i fix it. my problem is to understand why they are allow it which i think its ridiculous, thanks for the solution