# PHP: Email validation and accepting email address from a certain domain

Tags: php

I am currently working with AJAX/JS to have form without a button click or page refresh. The inquiry I have is in regards of email validation. Right now the PHP code checks if an email address is valid or not. I would like to only have it accept emails from a certain domain. How can I achieve through php to accept only email address from `gmail`? [**Example**](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

**PHP for validation of email:**

```
if($_POST) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (preg_match('|^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$|i', $email)) {
        echo ('<div id="email_input"><span id="resultval">'.$email.'</span></div>');
    }
    else {
        echo ('<div id="email_input"><span id="resultval">Include a valid email address.</span></div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Php has an easy function to help you with checking if an email address is valid:

```
$isValid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

To check if the email adress is a gmail address, the following would do the trick:

```
list ($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
$isGmail = ($domain == 'gmail.com');
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. I wasnt aware of the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`, it is very useful!

Comment: I have used this validation and it considers aaaa@aaaa.2 as a valid mail address

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with your regex, [it won't validate all actual email addresses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

You have a built-in PHP function to check if an email is valid :

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

If this returns true, then you just have to check if the string ends with `@gmail.com`. Note that there may be [some strange issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553021/php-filter-var-email-error/8553106#8553106) with this function, because email validation standards can be surprising.

If you really want a regex which validates all email addresses, here it is :

`(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])`

Answer (score 2):

You should change you're regular expression to this

```
'|^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@gmail\.com$|i'
```